# register new order in odoo using a daemon

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I am currently doing a demon in pure python using 2 libraries in espesifica (spycogp2 and mysql-connector), because that demon what it does is get data from my website such as (products, customers, prices, quantities among others ).

In the cripts you can create the order by the demon, you can create N order quantities but there is an inconsistency to register each product in each order as we know in odoo where all the product is a One2Many.

I have developed the logic but behave inappropriately example:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="testing",host = "localhost", user ="jpozzo", password ="bicimoto*")
cur = conn.cursor()
hoy = str(datetime.now())
for element in request:
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM sale_order WHERE name = %s;", (element['orden'][1],))
    for row in cur:
        odooOrden.append(row[0])
for data in orden:
    print data['detalle-or'][0]['c_product']
    cur.execute("SELECT id ,default_code,list_price,name FROM product_template WHERE default_code = %s;", (data['detalle-or'][0]['c_product'],))
    for record in cur:
        print '------------------------------Final---------------'
        detailproduc.append({'products':[record[0] ,record[1] ,record[2],record[3]]})
print detailproduc
liste = [10,10]
print detailproduc
print 'entro'
for i , response in enumerate(detailproduc):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO sale_order_line (create_date,price_unit,product_uom_qty,price_subtotal,state,order_partner_id,order_id,write_date,product_id,name,sequence,price_total,product_uom,customer_lead)VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",\
    (hoy,response['products'][2],orden[i]['detalle-or'][0]['cantidad'],011,'draft',liste[i],odooOrden[i],hoy,response['products'][0],response['products'][3],11,0,1,0))
    conn.commit()
```

This is part of the code of the devil as you can see the last for is the one in charge of making the registration of the products here:
[image]

Well, so as not to complicate myself so much in one part of the code, I only made one query that brings me only 1 order from 1 client that coincidentally has 2 products. Then I must create 2 product in order_line which is the one2many in odoo and for that I did this cycle that without However I placed it before but to be specific it is this:

```
for i , response in enumerate(detailproduc):
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO sale_order_line (create_date,price_unit,product_uom_qty,price_subtotal,state,order_partner_id,order_id,write_date,product_id,name,sequence,price_total,product_uom,customer_lead)VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",\
            (hoy,response['products'][2],orden[i]['detalle-or'][0]['cantidad'],011,'draft',liste[i],odooOrden[i],hoy,response['products'][0],response['products'][3],11,0,1,0))
            conn.commit()
```

Finally when I launch the script for the first time it makes me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cron.py", line 5, in <module>
    instance.RegisterOrder("162.144.52.66" ,"bicimoto","7-%H1*Zl~&2,M&d]KD","bicimoto_autopartes" )
  File "C:\Users\RafaelC\Desktop\scripts-db\commun.py", line 73, in RegisterOrder
    (hoy,response['products'][2],1,011,'draft',liste[i],odooOrden[i],hoy,12,'TEST',11,0,1,0))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

but I register the order evidently without products as you can see:

[image]

[image]

Well, I create the order in perfect condition, but without deleting the existing order the for to register the products if it works:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJKPh.png)

[image]

to finish, the behavior is inappropriate because I only want to execute the scripts once and register the order with their products, not execute it twice so that it runs fine as it is happening to me.

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you use the WEB API of Odoo? You're bypassing every useful boundary (access rules, sanitizing of queries) of Odoo's ORM layer by using the database directly.

Comment: hello friend, I have no knowledge of WEB API of Odoo and I did not know if it worked for the objective that I want, that is to obtain records of the databases of my web page this in mysql and those records register them in odoo. this will be executed by a cron every 1 hour

Comment: If you have the possibility to write code for you webpage, then you can use the XMLRPC API of Odoo instead of doing something directly on the database. You can find the documentation for example for Odoo V11 [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/webservices/odoo.html).

Comment: Of course I understand how to connect to odoo and use the ORM but how would I connect to the website? I know how to connect to odoo through this service but not to the web page that is in php and mysql